# php string with all space changing

Tags: php, arrays, string, permutation

I have string like this : `hello world new foo`.

I need to have array like this:

```
[
  `helloworld new foo`,
  `hello worldnew foo`,
  `hello world newfoo`,
  `helloworldnew foo`,
  `hello worldnewfoo`,
]
```

order doesn't matter but i need to have all case that space will be remove in current string.

Comment: So have you tried anything to create this array from this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to enumerate all the posibilities:

```
<?php

function combine($words, $acc=array(), $res=array()){
    if(count($words)===0){
        $res[] = join("", $acc);
        return $res;
    }
    if(count($words)===1){
        $res[] = join("", $acc).$words[0];
        return $res;
    }
    $w1 = array_shift($words);
    $res = combine($words,  array_merge($acc, array("$w1")),  $res);
    $res = combine($words,  array_merge($acc, array("$w1 ")), $res);
    return $res;
}

var_dump( combine( explode(' ', 'hello world new foo') ) );
```

Another possible solution is to represent the N spaces betweeen your words, as bits in a binary number that can be on or off, and then count from 0 to 2^N-1, but I think that in PHP that will be more complex.

NB: the above recursive solution, returns *all* possible combinations ... so if you have an input array with 4 words, one of the results will have *all 4 words joined*.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understood you need all posible combinations with the words given. so:

1. posible combinations = amountofwords*amountofspaces.
2. start iteration for amout of posible cominations. -> `for(i=0;i<=(words*spaces);i++)`
3. have words in array and spaces found in `String` so `$WordArray = $string.split(" ")` and `$spaces = substr_count(" ")`
4. start iteration for posible word combinations. `for(j=0;j<=words;j++)`
5. start iteration for amount of spaces. `for(k=0;k<=spaces;++)`
6. combine all.

but keep in mind that `PERMUTATIONS and COMBINATIONS for computer science` is what you need to learn first, so the answer above has a lot of sence.

here is a link to get you started.
http://cpsc.ualr.edu/srini/DM/chapters/review3.4.html